# Is a soap and water gas leak detecting solution more likely to cause rust than the store's version?

Tags: plumbing, leak, gas, rust, gasleak

Will a water and soap solution (one tsp of soap in a cup of water) cause a pipe to rust more than BrassCraft Gas Plastic Water Heater Gas Leak Detector?[image]

Comment: I doubt there's a list of ingredients on that bottle (unless it has an MSDS), but I'd be shocked if it were anything _more_ than soapy water... It probably has instructions to _not_ shake it, as that will cause the soap to bubble.

Comment: Usually also a bit of glycerine for more bubble persistence (take longer to pop, so easier to see.) Which is, of course, also easy to DIY. Or you can get a premade version that comes with a bubble-blowing wand at "mass produced children's toy" pricing.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Neither should cause any problem if the solution is dried off after.

Answer (score 0):

Absolutely dish detergents with chlorides corrode gas line metal! My lines were installed 5 years ago and the residue the plumbers’”soapy water test” left behind ate holes in the metal.  Use what the gas company recommends.

Comment: Are we talking about black iron pipe here, brass fititngs as you'd find with CSST, or copper tubing?

Answer (score 0):

Rinse and dry after testing if you are nervous. Dawn attests that it is non-corrosive.